# Mui autocomplete with react hook form always return null

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

As I want to have a form generator with MUI, Yup, and React Hook Form in my React app with the principle of giving a schema then generating a form with its validations, everything is correct except the final value of autocomplete is stuck at null and it’s like it can never be changed.

This happening when I submit my form but I didn't get it the null value when I check it with value.watch() .
it's like exactly after submit something cast my value to null

and this is my validation error below of my autocimplete input in production version

```
services must be a `object` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value `[ { "name": "\"Movement Plan\"" }, { "name": "\"Food Plan\"" }, { "name": "\"Sport Plan\"" } ]`). If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`
```

this is my autocomplete component

```
import { Controller, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import { AutocompleteValue, FormHelperText, TextField, styled } from '@mui/material'
import { CustomInputProps } from 'src/types/forms/muiForm'
import Autocomplete, { AutocompleteProps } from '@mui/material/Autocomplete'

export const AutocompleteMuiForm = ({ ...props }: CustomInputProps) => {
  const {
    control,
    formState: { errors, defaultValues, isSubmitting, isDirty },
    setError,
    watch,
    setValue,
    clearErrors,
    getValues,
    unregister
  } = useFormContext()
  const { t } = useTranslation()

  const error = `${t(`${errors[props?.name]?.message}`)}` as string | undefined

  if (getValues(props.name).length !== 0 && errors[props?.name]?.type === 'required') {
    clearErrors(props.name)
    unregister(props.name)
  }
  console.log(defaultValues, 'defaultValues')

  return (
    <>
      <Controller
        name={props?.name}
        control={control}
        key={props?.name}
        render={({ field: { value, onChange, onBlur } }) => {
          // console.log(value, 'getValues')
          return (
            <Autocomplete
              multiple
              limitTags={2}
              disableClearable={value !== null}
              options={props.autoComplete?.options}
              id={props.name}
              value={value}
              isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => {
                return option[props.autoComplete?.getOptionLabel!] === value[props.autoComplete?.getOptionLabel!]
              }}
              // onChange={onChange}
              onChange={(event, data, reason, detail) => {
                setValue(props.name, data)
              }}
              onBlur={onBlur}
              getOptionLabel={option => option[props.autoComplete?.getOptionLabel!]}
              defaultValue={defaultValues ? defaultValues[props.name] : []}
              renderInput={params => (
                <TextField
                  error={Boolean(errors[props?.name])}
                  label={t(`${props.label}`)}
                  placeholder={t(`${props.autoComplete?.placeholder}`)}
                  {...params}
                />
              )}
            />
          )
        }}
      />
      {error && <FormHelperText sx={{ color: 'error.main' }}>{error === 'undefined' ? '' : error}</FormHelperText>}
    </>
  )
}
```